# Windows gives strange 8-byte hardware addresses

Tags: windows, qt, networking, hardware, mac-address

I get the list of MAC addresses using Qt on Windows and Ubuntu Linux. The following code is used:

```
QString getMacAddresses()
{
    QString text;
    foreach(QNetworkInterface interface, QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces())
        if(!(interface.flags() & QNetworkInterface::IsLoopBack))
            text += interface.hardwareAddress() + ",";
    return text;
}
```

I tried it on several computers.

It works fine on Ubuntu Linux: correct MAC addresses are returned.

And here is an example output on Windows (formatted for convenience):

```
00:FF:B0:9B:AA:10
00:A0:C6:00:00:17
EC:F4:BB:6F:DD:3D
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:E0
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:E0
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:E0
```

**What are those strange 8-byte "MAC addresses"?** They certainly are not real MAC addresses, because it can be only 6 bytes long.

Used Windows version is Windows 7.

On different machines, the number of the strange addresses can vary from 2 to even 6. This number of addresses can even change after Windows updates. And they are always in the end of the list, after real MAC addresses.

The output of `ipconfig /all` for this example is (some lines were removed due to security reasons):

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXXXXXXX
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-B0-9B-AA-10
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Mobile Broadband adapter Mobile Broadband Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 5570 HSPA+ (42Mbps) Mobile Broadband Card #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-A0-C6-00-00-17
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : EC-F4-BB-6F-DD-3D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3de4:95c1:524a:19ab%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.33.203.146(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.33.203.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D7CEA001-3A2F-4ACA-BB3F-3237AACB4DA6}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{6285C284-8B28-4616-83AE-23E2DDA9DCBE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{576DFB96-0921-4F13-A7F8-956896780357}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

The documentation on [QNetworkInterface::hardwareAddress()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkinterface.html#hardwareAddress) says:

> Returns the low-level hardware address for this interface. On Ethernet
>   interfaces, this will be a MAC address in string representation,
>   separated by colons.
>
> Other interface types may have other types of hardware addresses.
>   Implementations should not depend on this function returning a valid
>   MAC address.

So, this method can return "other types of hardware addresses". What are they? Why is it always the same string "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:E0"?

Comment: The significance of the particular hardware address used by these virtual interfaces isn't documented as far as I know.  But there's no particular reason why we would need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue has nothing with Qt since ipconfig returns the same. It is the known problem of Vista and Windows 7.

You may want to read this for example:

http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/108910-problem-find-out-mac-address.html

Comment: It's not a "known problem".  It's a known behaviour.  The problem is that some people assume "hardware address" == "ethernet MAC address". :-)